# Ubuntu Display Issues

Tags: 12.04, installation, graphics

I installed 12.04 about 3 days ago. I was not very happy with the results,  when I start, it takes a lot of time. I have also display problems. For example, the movement of windows, the selection box, the movement of mouse pointer.

My colleague who recommended me to install Ubuntu told me that it requires many fewer requirements than Windows (XP in my case).

But anyway, when I installed Ubuntu, I installed it with the first option of the installer. I think that option says, "install Ubuntu, but keep Windows" or something, and asked me to allocate an amount of storage on my hard drive for each OS. I allocated 247 GB for Windows and 80 GB for Ubuntu.

I want to know if I can uninstall Ubuntu, and get back the storage allocated to it, return to Windows, along with those 80 GB, or just help me with these display issues.

I hope you understand me, I need help fast.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

You've described a problem in Ubuntu where your graphical user interface is slow and not sufficiently responsive. Usually it is possible to solve this problem by changing interfaces from Unity to Unity 2D.

To do this, go to the login screen. (If you are currently logged in, log out.)

Click on the Ubuntu logo near your name. A drop-down menu comes up. One of the items--which is probably currently selected--is called **Ubuntu**. Another is called **Ubuntu 2D**. Select that. Then log in.

Once you've logged in once with **Ubuntu 2D** as your session type, it will be remembered, and you'll log in that way in the future (unless you manually set it back to **Ubuntu** or something else).

With the **Ubuntu 2D** session type, the GUI does not use 3D graphics acceleration. On computers without fast video cards, this improves performance.

I hope that solves your problem, and that Ubuntu works well for you from now on. However, if you do decide to remove Ubuntu, you can do that, and the hard disk space taken from your Windows system can be given back to it. **[This answer explains how.](https://askubuntu.com/a/143482/22949)**